# Logging: Syslog for standalone applications?

Tags: c, logging, syslog

For a toy commandline application in linux, I decided to go the syslog way. With the LOG_PERROR option (which I understand is widely supported within the *nixes), I can also redirect log messages to stderr, which makes syslog almost perfect for my use.

My problem is that I have to sudo to `tail -f /var/log/user.log`, and I cannot find a way to tell syslog to output msgs from my application to a separate log *without* editing syslog.conf, which again would require me to sudo. It'll be unacceptable for me to require users of my application to have sudo privilegss just so that they can view its logs.

It seems to be okay as long as I'm getting a copy on stderr, but still there seems to be something amiss. So, un-doubt me, brethren:

1. Is it kosher for drive-by applications to use syslog for their logging needs?
2. How *widely* is LOG_PERROR supported?

No, I don't want to use a logging library.

Comment: how your application gives messages.?

Answer (score 1):

`syslog` isn't really designed for use by normal user applications.  It's intended for the system administrator's use.